# Why is this check constraint not working when it checks length?

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

```
create table test
(

   id varchar2(10) check( length(trim(id)) > 0),
   primary key(id)
)

insert into test values (' '); -- this works
```

I expected this check constraint to stop this insert. But, it gets inserted none the less. Why ?

Comment: Something doesn't seem right, separate from your specific question. If you do expect leading or trailing spaces, and you want to make sure the ID contains characters other than spaces (which seems to be the purpose of the constraint), why are you saving the ID with those spaces in the table in the first place? Why don't you store `trim(id)` as the primary key? Are you going to use `trim(id)` everywhere in your queries and other statements? Will foreign keys point to `id` or to `trim(id)`? Etc. Seems like the spaces should be trimmed before saving in the table.

Comment: @mathguy  even though trim(id) as a primary key looks likely to work and is an exciting lateral solution provided. I would like to keep the primary key expression clean. Best practice would be to validate the data in the constraint and prevent the insertion of blanks.

Comment: @mathguy alternatively we could use a BEFORE INSERT trigger as well - which would make a simple requirement complex unnecessarily. So, your contention that UNKNOWN is being treated as TRUE, holds true as the root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `TRIM(' ')` returns `NULL` and `LENGTH(NULL)` also gives `NULL` (not 0)

Try `NVL(LENGTH(TRIM(' ')), 0) > 0` or

Try `TRIM(ID) IS NOT NULL`

Snippet stating that constraints can return null aka 'unknown' and considered to be NOT VIOLATING the constraint. Only a return of false violates a constraint. At least as per Oracle 12c

[See Oracle Concept page about constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datainte.htm#CNCPT1660)

[image: Snippet stating that constraints can return null aka 'unknown']

Comment: so is "null" in oracle evaluating to true for that constraint !!! i thought that null meant UNKNOWN in oracle. thanks for answering - I used INSTR(ID,' ') > 0 as a check constraint instead

Comment: Also what is odd is why trim(' ') does not return a zero terminated string '' <=== like this ?

Comment: @user1561783 - The explanation is incomplete and it should be expanded. `null > 0` evaluates to **UNKNOWN**. In query conditions, **UNKNOWN** is treated as "the same as" **FALSE**. Not so in ***constraints***, however. In constraints, **UNKNOWN** is treated the same as **TRUE**. This is a very general rule, not special to the OP's constraint.

Comment: @user1561783 - your other question, about `trim('  ')`, suggests that you may be familiar with strings (in C, for example), and with empty strings, and with "empty string" not being the same as `null` (for example in the SQL Standard, and in some SQL dialects), but you are not aware that - idiotically - in Oracle the empty string is treated the same as `null`. This will cause a lot of difficulties for you if you are coming from a different dialect; you will have to learn to live with it, and to be surprised many times before you get really used to it.

Comment: @mathguy - have expanded the explanation above. I just needed an added reference from oracle itself to confirm the treatment of UNKNOWNs (aka null) in constraints

Comment: @user1561783 - for documentation, go to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm and find the **Check Constraints** section. The treatment of `UNKNOWN` is specified in the first paragraph in that section. (You can search for "unknown" on the page, it will take you straight to that paragraph.) Actually, let me write it all in an Answer; I don't like the `NVL` approach either.

Comment: @mathguy I concur that the meaning of null and zero-length strings do not match what we experience in languages like Java. Which brings me to the question that there would be a benefit in having null safe sql dialect as part of the SQL standard

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation for what you saw:**

1. If `str` is made up entirely of spaces, then `trim(str)` is the empty string.
2. Oracle treats the "empty string" the same as `null` (of `varchar2` data type, when that matters), in flagrant violation of the SQL standard. Oracle is not even consistent in this - there are (very few) exceptions where the empty string is, in fact, seen as "empty string" (for example, in concatenations).
3. By definition, the length of `null` is `null` (in particular, not zero).
4. In SQL, a condition like `null > 0` evaluates to `unknown` (in the three-valued logic needed to accommodate `null` in such conditions).
5. In **check constraints** `unknown` is treated the same as `true`. This is different from the treatment in other conditions (in SQL statements - in `where` clauses, join conditions etc.), where `unknown` is treated the same as `false`. This is documented, for example, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm - see the first paragraph in the **Check Constraints** section.

**The correct solution to your problem:**

Checking if something is null should be done **DIRECTLY**, with the `is null` or `is not null` conditions. Don't use `length` for that.

Like this:

```
check( trim(id) is not null )
```